# Context tentando excluir 2 vezes o mesmo registro

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

Estou com um problema, na verdade deve ser a falta de conhecimento mesmo, na hora de excluir um registro usando Entity Framework 6.

Quando tento excluir um registro que não pode ser excluído por ter referências, ele dá o erro a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até ai, tudo certo.

Ai vou tentar excluir outro registro, que eu tenho certeza que não tem referência, e ele dá o mesmo erro, na verdade está tentando excluir novamente o registro anterior.

Se eu sair da tela e entrar de novo ai eu consigo excluir o registro normalmente, desde que eu não tente excluir outro antes que gere o erro.

Alguém tem uma luz? Vlw

EDIT:
Segue meu código para entender melhor:

Assinatura da tela:

```
private readonly ICategoriaAppService _categoriaApp;
private CategoriaViewModel _categoria;

public FormCategorias(ICategoriaAppService categoriaAppService)
{
    _categoriaApp = categoriaAppService;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Método para excluir:

```
private void btnExcluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult resposta = MessageBox.Show("Deseja excluir este registro?", "Excluir", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    switch (resposta)
    {
        case DialogResult.Yes:
            var categoriaDomain = _categoriaApp.ObtemPeloID(_categoria.Numero_Categoria);
            _categoriaApp.Excluir(categoriaDomain);
            MessageBox.Show("Registro excluido com sucesso");
            break;
        case DialogResult.No:
            break;
    }
}
```

AppService:

```
private readonly ICategoriaService _categoriaService;

public CategoriaAppService(ICategoriaService categoriaService) : base(categoriaService)
{
    _categoriaService = categoriaService;
}

public void Excluir(TEntity obj)
{
    _serviceBase.Remove(obj);
}
```

Service:

```
public class ServiceBase<TEntity> : IDisposable, IServiceBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected ControleEstoqueContexto Db = new ControleEstoqueContexto();

    public ServiceBase()
    {
        Db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    }

    public virtual void Remove(TEntity obj)
    {
        try
        {
            Db.Set<TEntity>().Remove(obj);
            Db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Db.Dispose();
            Db = new ControleEstoqueContexto();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    //ETC
}
```

EDIT 2: Resolvido colocando o try catch e refazendo o Db.Context. Código acima alterado.

Comment: Pode colocar seu código na pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colocando o seu código fica mais fácil apontar o problema.

O que parece está acontecendo com você é o seguinte.

```
Contexto.Objetos.Remove(instancia1);
Contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Erro... Depois do erro você faz:

```
Contexto.Objetos.Remove(instancia2);
Contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Sendo que `instancia2` não tem chave. Só que o contexto ainda está com a "ordem" de excluir a `instancia1`. E ele tenta excluir as duas instancias. Logo, toma erro na tentativa de excluir a 1. Entendeu? Depois do erro refaz o contexto, ou ve a melhor lógica para você (não em seu código fica difícil dizer qual seria) e testa.

Quando você fecha a tela e abre de novo o contexto é refeito, por isso quando vc refaz apenas o `Remove(instancia2)` ele funciona.

**ATUALIZANDO**

Você no load do form injeta um instancia do contexto (bem legal). Durante a execução dos eventos você vai usando o mesmo contexto.

**Primeira coisa que eu faria é tratar o erro, ou fazer ele excluir o relacionamento ou não deixar nem chegar aí. Isso é o que eu sugiro.**

Caso não seja possível o mais indicado é fazer é criar o new, mas não esquece de fazer um `Dispose()` do atual.

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5468570/3517631) tem outra resposta sugerindo também o `new` em vez de mudar o status do objeto que está para ser excluído.

Comment: Ricardo, obrigado. Editei a pergunta com o código. Mas entendi o que quis dizer. Quando você diz para refazer o contexto é colocar um "new Contexto" quando der o erro?

Comment: Editei a resposta, acho que agora fica mais completo, não deixa de ver o link que coloquei, espero que tenha te respondido.

Comment: Ricardo, Vlw. Quanto a tratar o erro, com certeza farei isso. Também acho melhor. Porém, nunca se sabe, outro erro pode ocorrer, e preciso deixar da melhor forma possível. Eu tentei dar o Db.Dispose(); e depois o Db = new ControleEstoqueContexto(); logo apos o rollback. Ele até funciona, mas não efetiva a exclusão no banco. Até olhei pelo trace do SQL, ele até refaz as consultas para carregar o contexto de novo, mas nada foi alterado. Só pra deixar claro, coloquei uma transação na exclusão só para testar isso.

Comment: Não entendi se no final deu tudo certo ou não rsrs. Edita a pergunta lá com o código novo e o resultado, caso não tenha dado certo.

Comment: Editei lá, coloquei umas das tentativas. Pois é, não dá erro, mas também não efetiva a exclusão do registro no banco, rsss. Tentei dar um reload na entidade voltar o state para Unchanged, mas nada resolveu.

Comment: Pelo seu comentário você fez um begin na transação, mandou salva, conferiu no banco, não viu a exclusão e deu rollback, foi isso? Pq se der begin vc não vai ver nada no banco até dar commit.

Comment: Rsss, my bad. Na pressa esqueci do commit. Brigadão Ricardo. Vou alterar a pergunta para deixar como ficou no final. Vlw

Answer (score 0):

No seu lugar, eu não injetaria no form um serviço, e sim um contexto. [Um tutorial da Microsoft vai exatamente nesta linha](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx).

Isto é mais um problema do contexto destacado. Você carrega os dados usando um contexto e tenta a persistência usando outro contexto.

Comment: Olá Cigano. Ao meu entender o tutorial é não tem como foco o EF em si. Mas, mesmo assim, não ficaria tudo no front? Exemplo, no momento da inclusão de um registro, tenho algumas lógicas de negócio pra fazer, e realizar outras inclusões dependendo dessa lógica, inclusive tratar tudo dentro de transação. Esse tipo de coisa não deveria ficar no meu domínio?

Comment: Primeiro faça funcionar tudo no Front, depois você separa por camadas. Fica mais simples de você entender os erros daqui por diante.

Comment: Farei isso. Vlw.