# Entity Framework 6: Erro ao salvar - Instâncias de IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Domínio

```
public class Agenda
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public string HoraInicial { get; set; }

    public string HoraFinal { get; set; }

    public string Local { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Treino> Treinos { get; set; }
}

public class Treino
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Objetivo { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Agenda> Agendas { get; set; }
}
```

Configurações das Entidades

```
public class TreinoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Treino>
{
    public TreinoMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Agendas)
            .WithMany(x => x.Treinos)
            .Map(x => 
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("Treino_Id");
                x.MapRightKey("Agenda_Id");
                x.ToTable("AgendaTreino");
            });
    }
}

public class AgendaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Agenda>
{
    public AgendaMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Treinos)
            .WithMany(x => x.Agendas)
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("Agenda_Id");
                x.MapRightKey("Treino_Id");
                x.ToTable("AgendaTreino");
            });
    }
}
```

Método que utilizo para salvar

```
public void Inserir(T obj)
{
    banco.Set<T>().Add(obj);
    banco.SaveChanges();
}
```

O objeto Agenda é preenchido da seguinte forma:
Preencho normalmente todas as propriedades via parâmetro, com exceção da property Treinos, ela vem nula.
Mas na AgendaViewModel, recebo as descrições dos treinos numa string e converto para Array.
Depois passo esse array para o método e recebo todos os objetos Treino. E, a partir daí, vinculo esses treinos a minha Agenda, e, finalmente, mando salvar. Abaixo está o tratamento do objeto.

```
public ActionResult NovaAgenda(AgendaViewModel agenda)
{
    var descricoesDeTreinosEscolhidos = agenda.TreinosEscolhidos.Split(',');
    var treinosDomain = _treinoApp.ObterTreinosPorDescricao(descricaoDeTreinosEscolhidos) as IEnumerable<Treino>;

    var agendaDomain = MapearAgendaViewModelParaAgenda(agenda);
    foreach(var treino in treinosDomain)
    {
        agendaDomain.Treinos.Add(treino);
    }

    _agendaApp.Inserir(agendaDomain); // Aqui que lança a exceção.

    return View();
}
```

A seguinte exceção é lançada (Não consegui formatar com a barra de rolagem vertical):

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
>   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.VerifyContextForAddOrAttach(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity)
>   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AddSingleObject(EntitySet entitySet, IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, String argumentName)
>   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddEntityToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean doAttach)
>   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
>   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
>   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
>   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.AddRelatedEntitiesToObjectStateManager(Boolean doAttach)
>   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AddObject(String entitySetName, Object entity)
>   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__c()
>   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
>   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
>   em System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
>   em ProjetoTeste.Infra.Data.Repositories.RepositoryBase`1.Inserir(T obj) na D:\Informática\Raphael\Projetos VS2015\ProjetoTeste\Codigo\ProjetoTeste\ProjetoTeste.Data\Repositories\RepositoryBase.cs:linha 54
>   em ProjetoTeste.Domain.Services.ServiceBase`1.Inserir(T obj) na D:\Informática\Raphael\Projetos VS2015\ProjetoTeste\Codigo\ProjetoTeste\ProjetoTeste.Domain\Services\ServiceBase.cs:linha 24
>   em ProjetoTeste.Application.Services.AppServiceBase`1.Inserir(T obj) na D:\Informática\Raphael\Projetos VS2015\ProjetoTeste\Codigo\ProjetoTeste\ProjetoTeste.Application\Services\AppServiceBase.cs:linha 28
>   em ProjetoTeste.Presentation.Controllers.AgendaController.NovaAgenda(AgendaViewModel agenda) na D:\Informática\Raphael\Projetos VS2015\ProjetoTeste\Codigo\ProjetoTeste\ProjetoTeste.Presentation\Controllers\AgendaController.cs:linha 69

Comment: Também duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104002/context-tentando-excluir-2-vezes-o-mesmo-registro/104033#104033 e de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112941/update-many-to-many-entity-framework-c/112946#112946 e outras.

Comment: A propósito, a resposta sobre [nunca usar repositório sobre Entity Framework](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696) foi devidamente atualizada para falar sobre este problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado Cigano! Entendi e deu certo aqui.
E desculpa ai, pensei que tinha que escrever outra pergunta por causa que queria resposta referente ao erro. E Também não sabia o nome desse erro (Contexto Destacado) agora sei hehe.. valeu mesmo